# How do I get which Control node currently has focus?

Tags: godot, gdscript

I'm trying to determine which [Control](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/stable/classes/class_control.html) node has just changed focus. Another Control node has been set up for using focus by changing the focus mode on the node to `All`. From within that node's script, I can tell if it has focus by checking [`has_focus`](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/stable/classes/class_control.html#class-control-method-has-focus). However, I want to tell from another script if it has changed focus.

I know that there's [`focused_entered` and `focus_exited` signals](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/stable/classes/class_control.html#signals) that I could listen to, but these components are pretty far away from each other on the component tree and I don't want to connect or bubble up the signals through a bunch of unrelated components.

The [Control documentation says](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/stable/classes/class_control.html#:%7E:text=Only%20one%20Control%20node%20can%20be%20in%20keyboard%20focus.):

> Only one `Control` node can be in keyboard focus.

Since there's only ever one node in focus, is there a global function that can determine what the single node currently has focus? How can I tell when the global focus has changed?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `Viewport` has a `"gui_focus_changed"` signal you can use for this. It will give you the Control that has focus each time it changes.

You can connect to it from code like this:

```
func ready() -> void:
    get_viewport().connect("gui_focus_changed", self, "_on_focus_changed")

func _on_focus_changed(control:Control) -> void:
    if control != null:
        print(control.name)
```

---

By the way, if you have a look at the source code for `get_focus_owner` ([here](https://github.com/godotengine/godot/blob/5271c971f346fcf3859f5872049f948afa4dba99/scene/gui/control.cpp#L2491)), the code has the `Control` ask the `Viewport` it is in for the focus owner. Which is you need a `Control` in the scene tree to use `get_focus_owner`.

By using `"gui_focus_changed"`, you don't have to use `_process` which runs every frame. And thus, you would have less CPU usage.

---

**Addendum for Godot 4:** `Control` no longer exposes `get_focus_owner`, instead use `get_viewport().gui_get_focus_owner()`.

Answer (score 3):

[`get_focus_owner`](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/stable/classes/class_control.html#class-control-method-get-focus-owner) is a global function that will get the node in focus, if any:

> Returns the control that has the keyboard focus or null if none.

It can be used in code in a few ways:

#### Every frame

```
var focused_node
func _process(_delta):
    focused_node = get_focus_owner()
    
    if focused_node != null:
        # Runs every time a frame is drawn
        print(focused_node.name)
```

#### Every focus change

```
var focused_node
func _process(_delta):
    var new_focused_node = get_focus_owner()
    if new_focused_node != focused_node:
        focused_node = new_focused_node
        if(focused_node != null):
            # Runs every time the focused node changes
            print(focused_node.name)
```

#### Every focus change of a certain type of node

```
var focused_node
func _process(_delta):
    var new_focused_node = get_focus_owner()
    if new_focused_node != focused_node:
        focused_node = new_focused_node
        if(focused_node is Button):
            # Runs every time the focused node of a specific type changes
            print(focused_node.name)
```